# Recyclerview data not fetched with coroutines

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display Firebase storage data to a recyclerview using coroutines. When I do it, it does not show images, it displays empty recyclerview.
Here is the code

```
private var imageList = ArrayList<ImageItem>()

onCreate() {
    ....
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
        getImages()
        updateAdapter()
    }

}

private suspend fun getImages() =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
            listResult.items.forEach { storageRef ->
                storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    imageList.add(ImageItem(it))
                }
            }
        }
}

private suspend fun updateAdapter() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

when I put delay(1000) at the end of getImages() the data gets displayed correctly.
Please help

Comment: `addOnSuccessListener` won't run at the same time, coroutine will exit before it has completed. You can call `updateAdapter` after the forEach loop.

Comment: If you don't like to put he updateAdapter inside the callback, let me know the type of `storageReference.listAll()` to help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addOnSuccessListener` won't be invoked at the same time it has been assigned, coroutine will exit before it has completed. You can call `updateAdapter` after the forEach loop.

**Example:**

```kotlin
// onCreate
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    getImages()
}

private suspend fun getImages() =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
            listResult.items.forEach { storageRef ->
                storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                    imageList.add(ImageItem(it))
                }
            }
            updateAdapter()
        }
    }
```

Or you can make use of [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines.experimental/suspend-coroutine.html), if you like to use the same architecture you're currently using.

```kotlin
// onCreate
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
    getImages()
    updateAdapter()
}

private suspend fun getImages() =
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        suspendCoroutine { cont ->
            storageReference.listAll().addOnSuccessListener { listResult ->
                listResult.items.forEach { storageRef ->
                    storageRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                        imageList.add(ImageItem(it))
                    }
                }
                cont.resume(Unit)
            }
        }
    }
```